# Symfony: how to setup a development environment for bundles

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I want to create a new bundle **my-bundle** that I can use withing many other Symfony 3 apps that I have, such as **my-app** with the flowing dir structure.

```
projects
  my-app
    composer.json
  my-bundle
    composer.json
```

**my-app/composer.json**

```
"require": {
    "my-bundle": "*"
...

"repositories": [
  {
    "type": "path",
    "url": "../my-bundle",
      "options": {
          "symlink": false
      }
  },
...
```

**my-bundle/composer.json**

```
  "require": {
    "symfony/cache": "^3.*"
...
```

When I run the application it throws a ServiceNotFoundException:

```
The service "mybundle.some_service" has a dependency on a non-existent service "cache.app".
```

My 1st question is: why the service is not found although the dependency was installed by my-bundle inside `vendor/my/bundle/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/cache.xml`

Second question: why composer install didn't install the required `symfony/cache` bundle inside of my-app?